# How to delete selected row in titanium tableview?

Tags: javascript, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

i make simple application on titanium using table view. I have some custom row with checkbox on the left side. Here's my code :

```
    var pickingData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i<25; i++){
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className:'forumEvent', // used to improve table performance
            backgroundSelectedColor:'cyan',
            layout:'vertical'
        });

        if (Titanium.Platform.osname === 'android'){
            var checkbox = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
                style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
                value:false,
                left:10
            });
            row.add(checkbox);
        }

        var rndMatNo = (randomInt(50000)+10000) //randomInt is my random number function
        var lblMatNo = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            realValue:rndMatNo,
            text:'Mat No : ' + rndMatNo,
            font:{fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize:DefaultFontSize, fontWeight:'bold'},
            left:10,
            color:'#222'
        });
        row.add(lblMatNo);

        pickingData.push(row);
    }

    var tempPickingTable =  Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        data:pickingData,
        editable: Titanium.Platform.osname === 'iphone' ? true : false,
        name:'Picking table'
    });

    tempPickingTable.addEventListener('longclick',function(e){
        for (var i=0, length=tempPickingTable.data[0].rows.length;i<length;i++){
            if (tempPickingTable.data[0].rows[i].children[0].value === true){
                tempPickingTable.deleteRow(i); //Still error when i'm using delete row because index out of bound
            }

        }
    });
```

all i want is delete the row based on checkbox when it checked. i've tried looping for every row and check the checkbox and then delete the row, but it still give me error index out of bound.

has anyone know how to do that? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating forward through the array, and deleting the rows, which modifies the array, so it makes sense that you'd go out of bounds. Have you tried iterating backwards?

```
tempPickingTable.addEventListener('longclick',function(e){
    for (var i=tempPickingTable.data[0].rows.length;i>=0;i--){
        if (tempPickingTable.data[0].rows[i].children[0].value === true){
            tempPickingTable.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some bugs in deleting rows from `TableView` in Android. You can try to create a new data array with all the rows except the ones that have been checked and then set the data for the tableview again.

Comment: Hi Sapan.. thank for your comment.. :) but i looking for the other ways.. thanks again :D

Comment: "There are bugs" is rather insubstantial, don't you think? Especially in this instance where the real problem is the algorithm. You did provide a decent workaround, though...